# jQuery.addClass not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

This looks valid but it's not working.  I'd like the 'huh' div to become opaque when the menu is hovered over.  I tried this with fadein/out and it worked but just the once which was odd.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {
        $('#menuNav').hover( function() {
            $('#huh').addClass('.opacity');
        }, function(){
            $('#huh').removeClass('.opacity');
        });
    });

</script>

.opacity {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: Don't mention `.` in `addClass/removeClass` method. Check [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use it without dot:

```
 $(function(){

        $('#menuNav').hover(function(){

            $('#huh').addClass('opacity');
        }, function(){
            $('#huh').removeClass('opacity');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$( function() {
    $('#menuNav').hover( function() {
        $('#huh').toggleClass('opacity');
    });
});
```

Comment: Correct answer but tell people what the did wrong next time so they can learn

Answer (score 6):

`.hover()` makes many events, better to use `.mouseenter()`. **Note also** that when adding class you don't have the `.` (dot).

```
$(function(){

        $('#menuNav').mouseenter(function(){

            $('#huh').addClass('opacity');
        }, function(){
            $('#huh').removeClass('opacity');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Used this Remove `.`

```
    $('#huh').addClass('opacity'); // remove .

 $('#huh').removeClass('opacity'); // remove .
```

## ==============

**Or used to**

```
toggleClass in jquery
```

---

```
$(function(){

        $('#menuNav').hover(function(){
            $('#huh').toggleClass('opacity');
        });
    });
```

**[More about this](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
    $('#menuNav').hover(function(){
        $('#huh').addClass('opacity');
    }, function(){
        $('#huh').removeClass('opacity');
    });
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `.` in your class name in `addClass` and `removeClass`, you need to add and remove without the dot when calling these methods. i.e.

```
$(function() {
    $('#menuNav').hover(function(){
        $('#huh').addClass('opacity');
    }, function(){
        $('#huh').removeClass('opacity');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.` remove and then use this javascript

```
 $(function(){
    $('#menuNav').hover(function(){
        $('#huh').addClass('opacity');
    }, function(){
        $('#huh').removeClass('opacity');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#menuNav").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#huh').addClass('opacity');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#huh').removeClass('opacity');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Example: Change `h1` font color using `jquery`:

```
$(function(){$('h1').addClass('correct');});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not correct and hover functionality is also missing in the solution. Only "."(dot) was the problem.